# Structure pointer address assignment produces an error

Tags: c

Please clarify my doubts on structure pointer in below
  I have structure like below

```
struct ip_node {
      char arr[6];
};

typedef struct ip_node ip;

ip ip1={"abcde"};

case 1: // it is running without error
ip *ip2=&ip1;

case 2: // it is giving error
ip *ip2;
ip = &ip1;
```

I thought both cases are same.

Why does the second case give an error?

Comment: C != C++. Tag with only one.

Comment: `ip` is a type-name, not a variable. Do you mean `ip2 = &ip1;`?

Comment: In the second case you should write ip2 = &ip1

Comment: yes .i.e ip2=&ip1;    just typing mistake

Comment: I think this question should be closed as a "typographical error".

Comment: @tambre VTC as typo.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I flagged it, but can't vote to close, as I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @tambre no worries, we both did our part. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do exactly same thing, assignin address of variable to pointer which is correct.  You have just typo.

Change

```
ip = &ip1;
```

to

```
ip2 = &ip1;
```

Where you tried assign value to type.

**[Here is the correct example.](https://ideone.com/mlh3Oh)**

Comment: I am using gcc with ubuntu OS .when i run that it gives the following error.  warning: data definition has no type or storage class
 ip2=&ip1;
 ^
 warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘ip2’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 error: conflicting types for ‘ip2’
 note: previous declaration of ‘ip2’ was here
 ip *ip2;
     ^
 warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 ip2=&ip1;

Comment: @RatheeshT Please open 'Here is the correct example' in my answer and take a look.

Comment: the code is working which you have posted. I made one change in your code .i.e. changed the structure pointer assignment as global instead of local it gives the same error. Modified Code is here for your reference        
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
struct ip_node {
      char arr[6];
};
 
typedef struct ip_node ip;
 
    ip ip1={"abcde"};
 
    ip *ip2=&ip1;
 
    ip *ip3;
    ip3 = &ip1;
int main()
{ 
    printf("&ip: %p == ip2: %p == ip3: %p\n", (void*)&ip1, (void*)ip2, (void*)ip3);
 
}

Comment: Here `ip ip2=&ip1;` you have forgot an asterisk. It must be `ip *ip2=&ip1;` Also you cant set variables outside of function `ip3 = &ip1;`. :-)

Comment: Sorry for that asterisk missing,  but ip *ip2=&ip1; is also outside of function and that is working. Then why ip3 =&ip1; is not possible outside function?

Comment: Outside of function, you may assign value to variable just in declarating variable. I think its implementation defined but iam really not sure about this. You may try to google it :-)

Comment: Thanks for reply. i am trying that also. if you comes to know, please let me know

Comment: Sure have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

```
ip = &ip1;
```

is so invalid as the same as doing:

```
int = 1;
```

you need a name for that type `ip`, and that type should be a pointer because you are doing `&ip1;`

```
ip* a2 = &ip1;
```